# Como recorrer una tabla en powerpoint con vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

necesito poder recorrer una tabla creada en powerpoint y asignar un color de fondo a la celda segun el valor que tenga dentro.

El codigo que llevo hasta el momento es el siguiente, pero no logro ver donde estoy fallando.

```
Sub cuenta()
Dim totalfilas As Long
totalfilas = ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(4).Table.Rows.Count
MsgBox totalfilas
For x = 1 To totalfilas
    If x.cell(1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "-0.1 mm" Then
        x.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(500, 105, 0)
        End If
Next
MsgBox x
End Sub
```

Comment: Hola ¿Cuántas columnas tienen la tabla? y ¿Necesitas recorrer todas las celdas de todas las filas/columnas o alguna columna en particular?

Comment: Hola, tiene 4 columnas y necesito recorrer toda la columna 2 y que por ejemplo hay una. Celda que tenga el valor 3 la pinte de color rojo, y si hay una celda con valor 20 la pinte amarillo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la nueva información que aportas, la solución sería la siguiente:

```
Sub cuenta()

Dim totalfilas As Long, x As Long
Dim valor$

With ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes(4).Table

    totalfilas = .Rows.Count

    For x = 1 To totalfilas

        valor = .Cell(x, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
    
        If valor = "-0.1 mm" Then
            .Cell(x, 2).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 105, 0)
        End If

    Next x

End With

End Sub
```

No te olvides que los valores RGB son de 0 a 255. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, probé el código, pero no me colorea todas las celdas que cumplen con los -0.1 mm, a que se puede deber?

Comment: Hola nuevamente. Probablemente haya diferencias que no has notado;  por ejemplo no es lo mismo "-0.1 mm" que "-0.1 mm " o que "-0.1  mm" ¿notas las diferencias? Pero si es eso, pues solo tú puedes saberlo/verlo.  De no ser eso, es complicado dar una respuesta certera sin ver el archivo.

Comment: si, realice esos combaios que señalas, de echo borre el contenido y lo volvi a escribir aun asi no cambia de color, tambien copie y pegue las celdas que si cambian de color pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Lo otro, si quiero que me cambia 2 columnas de color 1 no solo una?
.Cell(x, 2).Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 105, 0)
que cambio debo realizar al codigo.

Comment: Lo otro es que coloques tu archivo en un drive y compartas por aquí el enlace, aunque no sé si las reglas lo permitan, pero no pierdes nada intentando. Si tienes información privada, solo bórrala.

Comment: Hola, disculpa nose si es la manera correcta.

Comment: no se entiende ¿Pudiste resolver el dilema o no? De ser no la respuesta ¿Por qué no compartes tu archivo? Si tienes datos privados, solo reemplázalos pero mantén la estructura principal para ver qué ocurre.

Comment: si lo resolví, cambiando la variable valor a float, y elimando los mm "-0.1 mm"

Comment: Ajá, excelente. Saludos.